# Not calling Post Data

Tags: php, javascript, html

Im having trouble trying to call POST data on my page, 
My form is...

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="getdata.php">
<input type="hidden" id="TimeToRenderHoursInput" name="TimeToRenderHoursInput" value="" />
<input type="hidden" id="TimeToRenderDaysInput" name="TimeToRenderDaysInput" value="" />
<input type="hidden" id="TimeToRenderYearsInput" name="TimeToRenderYearsInput" value="" />
<input type="hidden" id="ContentMinutesInput" name="ContentMinutesInput" value="" />
<input type="hidden" id="ContentMinutesSelector" name="ContentMinutesSelector" value="" />
<input type="hidden" id="PriorityInput" name="PriorityInput" value="" />
<input type="hidden" id="AvgFrameRenderTimeInput" name="AvgFrameRenderTimeInput" value="" />
<input type="hidden" id="AvgFrameRenderTimeSelector" name="AvgFrameRenderTimeSelector" value="" />
<input type="hidden" id="CoresInTestInput" name="CoresInTestInput" value="" />
<input type="hidden" id="EstPriceInput" name="EstPriceInput" value="" />

<input type="image" src="images/CONTINUE.jpg" style=" border:none; padding:0; width:206px; height:41px; float:right; display:none;" id="continue" />

</form>
```

and my php page which should get the data is

```
<?php 
$quantity = $_POST['TimeToRenderHoursInput'];
echo $quantity; 
?>
```

The values in my form are populated before its sent using Javascript...

Comment: Try doing `print_r($_POST)` to see if any data is sent, it looks good from the example.

Comment: write `<input type="submit" >` in your form?

Comment: Thanks kokos, Im unfamiliar with print_r, it returns an array however, Array ( [x] => 74 [y] => 26 )

Comment: It should work with input=image, try removing all the style attribute to check if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write before closing the `<form>`

```
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Postdata" >
```

or wrap you **image** with submit button

```
<button type="submit" name="postdata" id="postData">
     <img  src="images/CONTINUE.jpg" style=" border:none; padding:0; width:206px; height:41px; float:right; display:none;" alt="Continue" title="Continue"/>
 </button>
```

and also debug by writing below on `getdata.php`

```
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($_POST);
 echo "</pre>";
```

**one more thing :** Just remove `display: none` from `<input type=image ... >` ( Thanks @johndodo)

---

**Note:** if you use image to submit a form then get the data using image name dimension like this ( **$_POST['submit_x']** OR **$_POST['submit_y']** )

```
<form >
<input type="image" name="submit" src="whatever" value="Continue"> 
</form> 

<? 
if($_POST){ 
   print_r($_POST); 
} 
if($_POST['submit_x'] || $_POST['submit_y']){ 
   echo "An image button was used"; 
}
```

Comment: That worked using input type="submit", is it not possible to use an image as submit then?

Answer (score 2):

Just remove "display: none" from:

```
<input type=image ... >
```

and it will work.

The accepted answer above works too, of course. Just thought I'd point out where you went wrong in your code.